# How to Log Laravel 404 Error With Details

Tags: laravel-4

Just as in the title, I am getting a 404 error in my `Log` but don't know where/why this error is happening cause my App is working fine without a problem.

Is there a way for me to log the error in details (the referral link) e.g

**Error**

```
[2014-11-30 05:44:13] production.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' in /home/domain/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteCollection.php:146
```

**Details**

```
Detail: User tried to access route http://domain.com/users
```

Thanks, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: By default, Laravel is configured to create a single log file for your application, and this file is stored in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log`. Do you have the `app/config/app.php` with `'debug' => true,`?

Comment: Yes, I have it and it log errors correctly. I want to know the route which gives the 404 error e.g maybe a user want to access `http://example.com/user`, I want Laravel to log the `URL` the user want to access that result to an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    Log::error( Request::url() );
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

or use `Request::fullUrl()` this includes query strings in the URL

You need to make the view.

Comment: `fullUrl()` is giving an error as undefined function

Comment: Forgot to add Request::

Comment: Your welcome! if you ever have any other laravel problems feel free to drop me a message

Comment: Where/which file does this snippet need to be placed for it to work?